# Isoperimetric inequality for general metric space

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, isoperimetric-problems

Consider some space $\mathcal{S}$ with metric $d$ and measure $\mu$.

For arbitrary set $H$ denote the $v$-bound of $H$ by $\delta_v(H):= \{x \mid x \notin H: \exists y \in H \text{ s.t. } d(x,y) \le v \}$.

Isoperimetic problem for $\mathcal{S}$ is the following:

Assume that $ \mu(\delta_v(H))$ is fixed. How large can be $\mu(H)$? (and for what $H$ the value $\mu(H)$ is  maximal [if the corresponding maximum exists]?)

I think that if $\mathcal{S}$ is a ``good'' space then the maximum should achieves for balls. Are there  results about this?

As I understand this is true for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and boolean cubes. How is it possible to generalized?

Comment: What  is  $v$ ? ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @MarkSapir some (positive) real number

Comment: If $v=2diam(S)$ then $\delta_v(H)$ seems to be always $S\setminus H$? What if $\mu(S)=\infty$?

Comment: @MarkSapir 1) yes. 2) I do not see problems for this (for example, if $\mathcal{S}=\mathbb{R}^n$ and we use standard Lebesgue measure...)